# WolframScript Causing Gibberish Characters When Printing to Console

Tags: scripting

Placing the following in `./file.wls`:

```
e1 = a (x + I y) E^(I θ)
ComplexExpand[e1]
```

and running `wolframscript -cloud -print all -file ./file.wls` yields a bunch of gibberish characters:

```
$ wolframscript -cloud -print all -file ./file.wls 
a*E^(I*Î¸)*(x + I*y)
a*x*Cos[Î¸] - a*y*Sin[Î¸] + I*(a*y*Cos[Î¸] + a*x*Sin[Î¸])
```

yet evaluating the same statements in Wolfram Cloud:

> [image]

I tried both `gnome-terminal` and `xfce4-terminal` and got gibberish characters in each attempt.

**EDIT:** If I try to use `InputForm` as in:

```
e1 = a (x + I y) E^(I θ)
e2 = ComplexExpand[e1]

Print[e1 // InputForm]
Print[e2 // InputForm]
```

then the result of `wolframscript -cloud -file ./file.wls` is still gibberish:

```
InputForm[a*E^(I*Î¸)*(x + I*y)]
InputForm[a*x*Cos[Î¸] - a*y*Sin[Î¸] + I*(a*y*Cos[Î¸] + a*x*Sin[Î¸])]
```

Comment: Try using `InputForm`

Comment: @Somos: See my edit.

Comment: Okay, the problem is $\theta$ which is a Unicode character. Somehow this gets mangled somewhere in the pipeline. `InputForm` is not the answer I hoped it would be. Sorry.

Comment: What you're seeing there is the result of exporting characters as Unicode but the stream not being able to handle that, basically. There is in effect an issue in the `CharacterEncoding` in the stream and in the export. What you can to there is manually convert like `ToString[e1, CharacterEncoding->"ASCII"]`

Comment: Try it using `\[Theta]` instead of $\theta$ in `file.wls`.  The output then shows $\theta$ in my gnome-terminal.

Comment: @LouisB that worked, thanks.